# Returning a reformatted and bound date

Tags: c#, xaml

I am having trouble converting a bound date value/field.  The field within the database has a field type of VARCHAR(12) with the format of "yyyy-MM-dd".  Where as the object it is binding too on the XAML view is a DatePicker.

When I pull-in the initial field - my Binding Converter seems to works (see below):

```
string MyString = value.ToString();
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(MyString, "yyyy-MM-dd",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
return dt;
```

However, I can't seem to convert it back.  With help, I am trying variations on the following - but without any luck so far.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(value.ToString(), "yyyy'|'MM'|'dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
return dt.ToShortDateString();
```

---

Working update - It's a bit longer that I would have liked, but this seems to do the trick:

```
    try
    {
        DateTime dt;
        string strValue = value.ToString();

        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(strValue, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
        {
            return dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        }
        else
        {
            return DateTime.MinValue;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return DateTime.MinValue;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the `DateTime.ToString()` method mentioned here [msdn doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I've tried that, but can't get it to work.  If I go into the Immediate Window, and simply type ?value.ToString("d"); - I get the message, "No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments

Comment: What is the type of `value`?

Comment: Thanks Babu - When pulling it (from the database) it's a string.  When putting it back, it's from the XAML/view DatePicker (so DateTime I believe).  I'm going to slightly modify my question, as I have a better way for the first part).

Comment: Could you try `DatePicker.Text` to get the string value of the date picker field and parse it? Since it's string in the db, you don't need to parse, instead, you can just store the string as it is.

Comment: It's part of a Binding Converter, so it's an object - but I'll give it another go.

Comment: Hi Babu - thanks for your help - I've found a fix (hope it's OK).